# Timelion expression for boolean fields

Tags: timelion

I am writing a Timelion expression where I want to plot only if the specified key is TRUE.

```
.es(index=xyz*, metric=count, timefield=evaluatedAt, split=APM.CREDIT_CARD.REQUESTED:1).label(regex='.* APM.CREDIT_CARD.REQUESTED:(.*) > .*', label='APM.CREDIT_CARD approved')
```

How can I add a filter where APM.CREDIT_CARD.REQUESTED is TRUE

Answer (score 0):

Nvm found it, I can use lucene query. I used .q("APM.CREDIT_CARD.REQUESTED:true")